# Getting the primary key of an newly inserted row in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a bunch of data which will insert into a table. This issue is that I need it to return the primary key to that table. I wasn't sure if there was things like:

```
 insert into TABLE (...) values (...) RETURNING p_key
```

or

```
 select p_key from (insert into TABLE (...) values (...))
```

I am making a workaround for a browser and saved information which will more or less add a row and then update it... but without the primary key, there is no way to update it as there is no reference to it.

I was looking online and found some examples via google, but it confused me slightly with these examples.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_(SQL)#Retrieving_the_key

http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/databases/ms-sql/threads/299356/returning-identity-of-last-inserted-row-uniqueidentifier

Wikipedia was saying that for SQL Server 2008 to use `OUTPUT` instead of `RETURNING`,  possible to use something like `OUTPUT p_key`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If you're inserting a whole set of rows, selecting the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` won't do. And `SCOPE_IDENTITY` also only works for (numeric) identity columns - sometimes your PK is something else...

But SQL Server **does** have the `OUTPUT` clause - [and it's very well documented on MSDN!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table(columns)
OUTPUT INSERTED.p_key, INSERTED.someothercolumnhere .......
VALUES(...)
```

Those values will be "echoed" back to the calling app, e.g. you'll see them in a grid in SQL Server Management Studio, or you can read them as a result set from your C# or VB.NET calling this `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I have a Primary Key that isn't a numeric value(uuid). Because of that Scope_Identity() does not work.

Comment: Then you need to look at the `OUTPUT` clause for your `INSERT` statement. This will return newly inserted values of *any* data type

Comment: It's worth noting that if the table you're inserting to has a trigger on insert, `OUPUT` will throw an error unless used in conjunction with `INTO`. Per the documentation: "If the OUTPUT clause is specified without also specifying the INTO keyword, the target of the DML operation cannot have any enabled trigger defined on it for the given DML action."

Answer (score 17):

`Scope_Identity()` is what you want, assuming that by "primary key" you mean "Identity"

```
declare @id int 
insert yourtable values (some, values)
select @id = Scope_Identity()
```

Comment: as 1 statement, or break it into 2?

Comment: @Fallenreaper - These statements need to be in a batch.

Answer (score 6):

In `C#`, right after your SQL Statement write `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();` so your code would be:

```
insert into TABLE (...) values (...); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

then, instead of `executeNonQuery` use `executeScalar`.

That should do the trick!

Comment: i actually am using C#, so it would look something like *CommandFaction cmd = new CommandFactory(); cmd.commandText = "insert into TABLE (...) value (...); select SCOPE_IDENTITY();"; [command to fire the query]*

Comment: in C# I usually use SqlCommand dbcm = new SqlCommand(query, dbconn); dbconn.Open(); string insertedID= dbcm .ExecuteScalar(); where query is the string with sql statement with the select scope_identity(). make sure that you use a command that returns a type rather than just executing so that you could get a value back from the results

Comment: kk, ill have to take a look at what i have onhand to use.  THanks for the info

Comment: just make sure that the statement i wrote above is one combined statement. therefore "insert into TABLE (...) values (...); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();" is one string with the statement. then use the code in the comment to execute where 'query' is the string with statements and dbconn is of type SqlStatement. Here's an example of how SqlStatement class works [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/a42fc25d-8fb1-4867-b9c8-f56923741205/). If you don't manage let me know.. if you do don't forget to make as answered :)

Answer (score 1):

After performing insert, query:

```
select scope_identity()
```

to retrieve last inserted primary key.

Comment: so i would insert into the db then call this, and it would return it?

Answer (score 1):

Using @@IDENTITY , you can get the last generated primary key

```
Insert into TableName (Name,Class) values('ABC','pqr')
select @@IDENTITY
```