# How do I convert the result of ExecuteScalar() to int?

Tags: c#

I am actually trying to get the primary key after the insertion by using `ExecuteScalar()`. Since it returns the first column of the first row after the insertion. But I am getting 0. I do not know why it is happening. Please help me out.

```
query = "Insert into Admissions(Admission_date, Student_name, Father_name, Mother_name, DOB, Gender, Address, State, City, Pincode, Admission_for, Previous_school, Fees) values ('" + txtAdmDate.Text + "','" + txtStudentName.Text + "','" + txtFatherName.Text + "','" + txtMotherName.Text + "','" + dob + "','" + gender + "','" + txtAddress.Text + "','" + txtState.Text + "','" + txtCity.Text + "','" + txtPincode.Text + "','" + cmbClass.Text + "','" + txtPreviousSchool.Text + "','" + txtFees.Text + "')";

cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
con.Open();

int admid = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Also: `INSERT INTO` returns nothing - therefore, you get 0. You need to have  a statement that actually **selects** something that gets returned from the query, like `SELECT COUNT(*) .....` or something like that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080324/getting-the-primary-key-of-an-newly-inserted-row-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues with your code/question.

1. Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx) attacks.  You need to **parameterize your queries**.
2. The INSERT statement by design is **not meant to return anything**, if you want to return the primary key of what you just inserted you need an output parameter in your query (better yet, a stored procedure).
3. A quick google for "return primary key on sql insert c#" would have given you a ton of results. Your question is asked almost verbatim [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246744/executescalar-vs-executenonquery-when-returning-an-identity-value). In fact my answer is basically the top answers code (modified for your use).

**Here is my answer**

```
//Create an Admission class that represents your data
public static int Save(Admission admission)
{
    var conn = DbConnect.Connection();
    const string sqlString = "Admissions(Admission_date, Student_name, Father_name, Mother_name, DOB, Gender, " +
        "Address,   State, City, Pincode, Admission_for, Previous_school, Fees) values (@AdmissionDate, @StudentName, " + 
        "@FatherName, @MotherName, @DOB, @Gender, @Address, @State, @City, @Pincode, @AdmissionFor, @PreviousSchool, " +
        "@Fees) SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

    using (conn)
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdmissionDate", admission.AdmissionDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentName", admission.StudentName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FatherName", admission.FatherName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MotherName", admission.MotherName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", admission.DOB);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", admission.Gender);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", admission.Address);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", admission.State);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", admission.City);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pincode", admission.Pincode);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdmissionFor", admission.AdmissionFor);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PreviousSchool", admission.PreviousSchool);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fees", admission.Fees);

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            conn.Open();
            return (int)(decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an [OUTPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) clause in your SQL command to return information about your command.

Comment: ExecuteScalar()   executes the query and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query.  Why I am I getting 0 ?

Comment: @SATYA try executing the query in SQL. What are you expecting to return?

Answer (score 0):

```
public int NewProperty(PropertyData propertyData)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertUpdateProperty", con);

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", propertyData.ID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ListPropertyFor", propertyData.ListPropertyFor);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PropertyTypeId", propertyData.PropertyTypeId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PropertyLoction", propertyData.PropertyLocation);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Locality", propertyData.Locality);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectName", propertyData.ProjectName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PropertyDescription", propertyData.PropertyDescription);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SuperBulidupArea", propertyData.SuperBulidupArea);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SuperBulidupId", propertyData.SuperBulidupAreaId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BulidupArea", propertyData.BulidupArea);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BulidupAreaId", propertyData.BulidupAreaId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarpetArea", propertyData.CarpetArea);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarpetAreaId", propertyData.CarpetAreaId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bathrooms", propertyData.Bathrooms);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bedrooms", propertyData.Bedrooms);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Balconies", propertyData.Balconies);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FurnishedId", propertyData.FurnishedId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalFloors", propertyData.TotalFloors);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PropertyOnFloors", propertyData.PropertyOnFloor);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parking", propertyData.Parking);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AvalibiltyId", propertyData.AvalibiltyId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgeOfProperty", propertyData.AgeOfProperty);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerShip", propertyData.OwenerShip);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", propertyData.Price);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", propertyData.IsActive);

            con.Open();

            int i = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); 

            con.Close();
            return i;
        }
    }
```